# Understanding assertion methods

Tags: unit-test

I am asking about `System.assertNotEquals(ANY, ANY)` and `System.assertEquals(ANY, ANY)`.

What do I understand from this? Are the values matching?

Also for `System.assert(Boolean)`, how do I understand whether it returned `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: have you looked into documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to use assertions to accomplish something they weren't meant to do. Assertions are pretty much a tool to use in unit tests, and nowhere else.

The System assertion methods don't return any value. If you [look at the documentation that @Ratan linked](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm), you can see that the assertion methods have a return type of `void`.

The entire purpose of assertions is to inform you when things didn't turn out as expected, and to do so in a very in-your-face manner. It follows the idea that **in debugging, information about when things go wrong is more valuable than information about when things go right**.

If your assertion holds true it quietly executes, and then your code continues to execute.

If your assertion is false it will throw an exception. Not just any exception though, it throws something called an uncatchable exception. This special variety of exception will immediately halt the execution of your code *and there's nothing you can do to stop that*.

If you have an assertion that fails, you will know about it. You will see the `System.AssertionException` in your log, and it will be one of the very last things in your log (unless you're running a test class, in which case the next test will start executing).

It's also considered good practice to include something for the optional `message` argument to help you understand exactly what the exception is complaining about.

> assertion exception: values did not match, expected: 2 actual: 3

isn't as helpful as

> assertion exception: attempted to calculate 1 + 1, expected: 2 actual: 3

Unless you're running a test class with multiple tests, you will never see a debug log with more than one assertion exception. This behavior makes exceptions, in general, good tools for alerting you to strange behavior but bad tools for trying to figure out the cause of that strange behavior. The task of figuring out the cause is better handled by `System.debug()` and [code checkpoints in the dev console](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en)

Comment: Thank you Derek . Your answer was really simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For System.assertNotEquals(ANY, ANY), you are comparing between two values, which will be true if two values does not matches and the assertion passes if it returns true.

For System.assertEquals(ANY, ANY), you are comparing between two values, which will be true if two values matches and the assertion passes if it returns true.

And for System.assert(Boolean), you write the value, or compare value which will return true or false and the assertion passes if it returns true.

Comment: My question was how do I understand from the debug logs whether the compared  values are same ? And how do I understand from the Boolean whether it's TRUE or False?

Comment: you can dump your values using extra parameters like 
System.assertEquals(account1.name, account2.Name, 'account 1 name is' + account1.Name+ '   '+account1.Name + 'account 2 name is' + account2.Name).
if the assertion fails it will show the message.
And if the boolean returns false, you can see the message in the debug log that the assertion failed.

Comment: So if I have system.assertEquals as System.assertEquals(YrCount , Yr.size()); -How do I understand from Debug log whether everything is alright?